# Jmeter returns 100% errors

Tags: http, jmeter

I am running a test in Jmeter, it works but shows 100% errors. What can be wrong?

request:
[image: request]

result in cmd:
[image: result in cmd]

log file
[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTNiY.png)

log file
[log file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxuK5.png)

Comment: You forgot www in the url

Comment: i try, but think it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

There are following problems with your test:

1. `/` is not allowed character in the [DNS hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) or [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), remove it from the "Server Name or IP" field

   you need to replace `google.com/` with `google.com`
2. You forgot to provide `-l` command line argument before `log.jtl` file

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Going forward check your [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), normally they contain sufficient troubleshooting details.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I changed the screenshots, the error still persists. I tried adding the whole url (www.google.com/doodles and www.google.com/) to the PATH, that didn't work either

Comment: If you cannot read English try using online translation tools as I believe I clearly stated that we need to see the error details from the .jtl results file and/or jmeter.log file in order to be able to help

Comment: yes, i saw that part of your comment but didn't find anything in the logs. I added screenshoots.